# Why does は refer to a particular rather than general in some cases?

Tags: particle-は, particle-が

The sentence I am asking about is the following

> [魚]｛さかな｝が[好]｛す｝きじゃない[人]｛ひと｝は、[肉]｛にく｝が[好]｛す｝きだ 」
> Person who does not like fish like meat
>
> <sup>Source: [Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/adjectives)</sup>

My understanding, which is probably flawed in some aspect, is that は after 「[魚]｛さかな｝が[好]｛す｝きじゃない[人]｛ひと｝」 should make the sentence mean "People (in general) who do not like fish like meat", since は would mean in general as opposed to a particular occurrence (が).

How, then, would the general form be conveyed (i.e. "People (in general) who do not like fish like meat")?

Comment: It's not clear what the English is intended to mean.

Comment: Tae Kim uses a kind of pseudo-English that tries to keep the word order the same as Japanese.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct and that website is incorrect on this matter.

Upon hearing/reading the sentence:

> 「​魚
> {さかな}
> ​が​好
> {す}
> ​きじゃない​人
> {ひと}
> ​は、​肉
> {にく}
> ​が​好
> {す}
> ​きだ。 」

Practically all Japanese-speakers will take the 「人」 to mean "***people in general***".
It is just ***extremely*** unnatural to form that sentence when the speaker/writer is referring to one particular person.

To alter the sentence so it talks about a particular individual, one could say:

> 「魚が好きじゃない〇〇さんは、肉が好きだ。」 or more naturally,
>
> 「〇〇さんは、魚**は**好きじゃないけど、肉**は**好きだ。」←Uses a pair of the contrastive 「は's」.